# Link error for CoInitializeEx, unresolved token

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, com

I created a CLR Class Library where I am wanting to do some WASAPI Core Audio processing.  Finally got around to adding the COM stuff, and I've stripped it all down to simply this:

```
bool AudioLibrary::AudioClass::initializeAudioDevices()
{
    HRESULT hr = CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);

    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        // Big problem
        return hr;
    }
}
```

This is extremely basic, and compiles just fine (my namespace is obviously AudioLibrary and the class is AudioClass).  However, during link I get this:

```
Error   9   error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A000029) "extern "C" long __stdcall CoInitializeEx(void *,unsigned long)" (?CoInitializeEx@@$$J18YGJPAXK@Z) referenced in function "private: bool __clrcall AudioLibrary::AudioClass::initializeAudioDevices(void)" (?initializeAudioDevices@AudioClass@AudioLibrary@@$$FA$AAM_NXZ)   C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\Visual Studio Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\AudioLibrary\AudioLibrary.obj  AudioLibrary
```

I've got Windows.h and objbase.h included, but I'm obviously missing some type of link reference.  I've tried both 'inherit from parent' and no inherit in the link options for the project.

Been doing too much IOS/Android/OSX programming lately so I'm apparently pretty stale on Visual Studio stuff.  What am I missing to include CoInitializeEx?  I'm using Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate.  Thanks!

Comment: COM programming: You need teaching from COM programming teachers abused by several COM programming teachers before. (Sorry, I consider COM a pale of junk)

Comment: I do have the 'basics' down (it's been more than 8 years since I dealt with COM).  I just hate that the development environment itself seems to be blocking me at this point.

Comment: You need to link with `ole32.lib`.

Comment: That was it, I knew it was stupid.  Thanks!